# Liquid images without upscaling

Tags: css

I'm working on a simple website that has to be responsive, so far everything is working, but in firefox my images aren't scaling. (While it works in Chrome)

I just used this to do that:

```
img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    display: block !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```

I could use `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` but I don't want images to upscale.

This seems fairly simple, why isn't firefox doing it correctly?

EDIT: This is an example of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/TC3qq/1/ (I know, tables, but it's an email template) http://jsbin.com/inanat/1/

Comment: can you show a fiddle or link to website how it's looking?

Comment: @Sarfaraz Here's a basic example, works fine in Chrome, doesn't work in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/TC3qq/1/

Comment: fiddle link is not opening

Answer (score 0):

You can target `img` by it's parent and this will work fine for example:

```
<div class="someclass">
   <img src="path-of-img" />
</div>
```

and css for this:

```
.someclass img{
  width:100%;
}
```

pls let me know if you have any problem

Comment: I'm actually doing that already, see this for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/TC3qq/1/

Comment: am unable to see your fiddle link